# Lightning artifacts in equirectangular map rendering with linear filtering

Tags: three.js

I'm seeing lightning like artifacts when rendering background HDR with `magFilter = LinearFiltering`. The background is a low res equirectangular map with extreme blurring baked into the image.

Code snippet:

```
new RGBELoader()
  .setDataType(THREE.UnsignedByteType)
  .load(this.background, (hdrtexture) => {
    hdrtexture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
    hdrtexture.encoding = THREE.RGBEEncoding;
    hdrtexture.name = this.background;
    hdrtexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    hdrtexture.needsUpdate = true;

    // If the gui is set to show the env map, set the background to be the new map
    if (this.params.showMap) {
      this.scene.background = hdrtexture;
    }
  });
```

[image: Lightening artifacts with hdrtexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;]

Without the linear filtering I see nearest filter issues (blocky pixellation) at the poles, hence why I'm applying the linear filter.
[image: nearest filter issue at the poles]

Whats the best way to remove these lightning artifacts? Convert to Cubemap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the equirectangular map to a cubemap solves the artifact issues.

Snippet:

```
    new RGBELoader()
  .setDataType(THREE.UnsignedByteType)
  .load(this.background, (hdrtexture) => {
    hdrtexture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
    hdrtexture.encoding = THREE.RGBEEncoding;
    hdrtexture.name = this.background;
    hdrtexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    hdrtexture.needsUpdate = true;

    const pmrem = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(this.renderer);
    const envMap = pmrem.fromEquirectangular(hdrtexture).texture;

    // If the gui is set to show the env map, set the background to be the new map
    if (this.params.showMap) {
      this.scene.background = envMap;
    }
  });
```